# Creating namespaces for a javascript library

Tags: javascript, namespaces, iife

I'm trying to create a library `foo.js` with a function `foo.bar` in it that I can call like so:

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
<script>
    baz = foo.bar();
</script>
```

I'm trying to write this library like so:

```
foo = function() {
    foo.bar = function() {
        // code goes here
    }
}();
```

which is a pattern I've seen used elsewhere, though I can't say I understand exactly what is going on. When I try to use this I'm told that `foo` is not defined when I try to define `foo.bar`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

read this book for js-patterns:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

its free, and its great!

inspired by dystroys answer i would change it a little bit and write it like this

```
var foo = (function () {

  // your private stuff here

  return {
    bar: function () {}
  };

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are so many possible patterns it's impossible to be sure of which one you wanted.

You can do this, for example :

```
var foo = (function(foo) {
    // here you can also declare "private" non exported variables,
    //   including functions that could be used by bar
    foo.bar = function() {
        // code goes here
    }
    return foo;
})(foo||{});
```

This would ensure `foo` exists and would add a `bar` function to `foo`. If `foo` doesn't exist before, it's created. If it exists before, it's just augmented.

The same logic can be used to create submodules, then it makes more sense.

Comment: foo and foo, it's a confusing world!

Comment: +1, I like this pattern. Then there's prototyping, literals, and a hundred others to choose from that does pretty much the same. For simple things I always use an object literal as I think it's easier to understand and keep track of, but I guess it's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: you need to return your inner foo!

Comment: dystroy was born with all his inner foo, so he doesn't have to return anything, you need to return your inner foo to dystroy.

Comment: Spaghetti++, not the way to do it. foo.bar must be this.bar. and create an new instance of it using new instead of using foo as parameter.

Comment: @Erwinus `foo` is a singleton here, not a constructor. It is just one of the many patterns available.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do this :

```
var foo = {
           bar : function() {
               // code goes here
          }
};
```

but that's an object literal, but can still be called with `foo.bar()`

Answer (score 0):

I would write my javascript modules today like this:

```
(function(exports){

    exports.greet = function(){
        return 'hello beloved world'
    };

})(typeof exports === 'undefined'? this['uebermodule']={}: exports);
```

So you could use your lib in the browser as well as in node.js

```
uebermodule.greet() // is uniform in node as in browser
```

[Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://www.2ality.com/2011/08/universal-modules.html) wrote on that topic.